# Flutter 2: Color issues

Tags: flutter, user-interface, colors, themes

I recently switched my code basis to Flutter 2.

Now I face certain problems with theming (colors):
[image]

1. The color of the device's status bar icons are black
2. The color of the TextField's context menu items are black

Previously they were white, so something seems to be changed in the new Flutter version.

I am using `ThemaData.dark()` and some specific colors. Especially I am setting `cardColor` to a dark grey to color the background of the `TextField`'s context menu:

```
ThemeData buildTheme() {
  final ThemeColors colors = themeColors();
  final ThemeData base = ThemeData.dark(); 
  return ThemeData(
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: colors.primaryBackground(),        // == dark grey
      primaryColor: colors.primaryBackground(),                   // == dark grey
      accentColor: colors.accent(),                               // == orange
      textTheme: base.textTheme,
      buttonTheme: base.buttonTheme.copyWith(
          buttonColor: colors.accent(),                           // == orange
          textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary
      canvasColor: colors.inputBackground(),                      // == dark grey
      inputDecorationTheme: base.inputDecorationTheme.copyWith(
        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: colors.textFieldHintText()),  // == grey
        fillColor: colors.inputBackground(),                      // == dark grey
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: colors.focused())),     // == green
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: colors.accent())),      // == orange
      ),
      unselectedWidgetColor: colors.accent(),                     // == orange
      cardColor: colors.messageBackground());                     // == dark grey
}
```

1. Do you know why the described colors don't turn into white when using the new Flutter version?
2. Do you know what I can do to fix that? Maybe change another color field of `ThemeData`?

My only idea is to remove the `cardColor` change, which yields a white context menu. But this does not fix the text color problem of the status bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your are just missing a tiny part.
You create a dark theme with `ThemeData.dark()` but then you create a light theme with `return ThemeData(...)`

Instead create the ThemeData directly with the intended brightness, all the values
that you do not specify will be defaulted depending on the brightness value in
the same way `ThemeData.dark()` does create them.

```dart
ThemeData buildTheme() {
  final ThemeColors colors = themeColors();
  return ThemeData(
      brightness: Brightness.dark,
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: colors.primaryBackground(),        // == dark grey
      primaryColor: colors.primaryBackground(),                   // == dark grey
      accentColor: colors.accent(),                               // == orange
      buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
          buttonColor: colors.accent(),                           // == orange
          textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
      ),
      canvasColor: colors.inputBackground(),                      // == dark grey
      inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: colors.textFieldHintText()),  // == grey
        fillColor: colors.inputBackground(),                      // == dark grey
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: colors.focused())),     // == green
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: colors.accent())),      // == orange
      ),
      unselectedWidgetColor: colors.accent(),                     // == orange
      cardColor: colors.messageBackground(),                      // == dark grey
   );                     
}
```

If you look in the implementation of `ThemeData` [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart#L781):

You find this: `factory ThemeData.dark() => ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.dark);`

And if you look [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart#L317) you can see that the default brightness is `Brightness.light` and in the following lines you can find out which defaults are created depending on the `brightness` value.

Be careful about using `ThemeData.copyWith` as there are no defaults set when calling this.

Comment: Thank you so much. The missing `brightness` was the point.

Answer (score 2):

For the `statusBar` only, you can set the brightness of the icons when defining the `AppBar`:

```
 AppBar(
        backwardsCompatibility: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
        systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
          statusBarColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
          statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
        ),
      ),
```

But with this settings your appbar wouldn't get the color from your theme.

You'll have to set background color and statusBarColor from there.

I did set Colors.grey.shade800 since I didn't have acces to your colors.

For the sistem UI, like the copy/paste, you can solve your problem by adding `brightness: Brightness.dark` inside your ThemeData.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, I will try. But for clearifying. I never change the status bar color intentionally. Until the change to Flutter 2 the color setting was fine. I didn't change my own theme - I just switched internally to Flutter 2. So there must be happened internally. However, I try to fix it by using the brightness attribute. But isn't it already part of ThemeData.dark()?

Comment: I think you are currently appying ThemeData.dark() only to textTheme, buttonTheme and inputDecorationTheme. Not to the whole app.

Comment: Thank you so much. The missing `brightness` was the point. Unfortunately, I can award the bounty only once, but I really appreciated your work!

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't modify the status bar colour in `AppBar` because then when you use a different app bar in a different part of the app, you might change it there.

I find it nicer to change the theme brightness, which might fix the issue with the text color theming too:

```dart
...
        theme: ThemeData(
          brightness: Brightness.dark,
          ...
        )
...
```

or alternatively:

```dart
...
        theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
          ...
        )
...
```

Otherwise you might just be using the wrong text theme.

Comment: In some cases, if the android os settings allow the user to set a dark or a light UI, that setting can override your brightness setting inside the app.
At least that's what happens in my Oneplus 6T.
By overring the status bar icons brightness in AppBar the problem is solved even in those cases.

Comment: Thanks, I will try. But for clearifying. I never change the status bar color intentionally. Until the change to Flutter 2 the color setting was fine. I didn't change my own theme - I just switched internally to Flutter 2. So there must be happened internally. However, I try to fix it by using the brightness attribute. But isn't it already part of ThemeData.dark()?

Comment: It is a part of it, but you're actually ignoring most of the properties because you are just using a few properties of `ThemeData base`. I've updated my answer to use the dark theme properly as per https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/themes#extending-the-parent-theme

Comment: Thank you so much. The missing `brightness` was the point. Unfortunately, I can award the bounty only once, but I really appreciated your work!

Comment: I understand. `copyWith` does in fact copy all the values from the theme you copied from, including the defaults, so kuhnroyal was wrong there.